# Qt QTreeView editable DOM model

Tags: xml, qt, dom, qtreeview, qtxml

I have a QTreeView to which I set a subclassed DomModel:QAbstractItemModel. Each item is a DomItem which deals mostly with QDomNode. I set QDomDocument to this model. I think I've derived this system from one of the Qt examples.

It has 3 columns: 0 for node name, 1 for attributes and 2 for value.

Anyway, I wanted to make this XML DOM tree editable. I've modified some flags such as Qt::ItemIsEditable and some other things in the model class and now I can edit the model through QTreeView by double clicking.

For column 2 it's easy, since QDomItem has this setNodeValue function, however I've found there are no "set" functions for item->node().NodeName() and item->node().attributes() which would, I presume, modify columns 0 and 1.

So now when I modify column 2 it works, however columns 0 and 1 revert to their previous values upon pressing enter.

```
bool DomModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value,
                    int role)
{
if (role != Qt::EditRole) return false;

DomItem *item = static_cast<DomItem*>(index.internalPointer());

switch (index.column()){
    case 0:
        // ???
        break;
    case 1:
        // ???
        break;
    case 2:
        item->node().setNodeValue(value.toString());   // This works - QTreeView is updated
        break;
}
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, apparently `item->node().toElement()` which returns a `QDomElement` has the necessary "`set`" functions and it works. So I think I've found a way to fully modify my `XML DOM` file through `QTreeView`.

This does the trick for me:

```
switch (index.column()){
   case 0: // added
      item->node().toElement().setTagName(value.toString());
      break;
   case 1: // added
      // this shall be modified to account for nonstandard spacings, etc.
      aux = value.toString().trimmed();
      aux.remove("\"");
      attributes.clear();
      attributes = aux.split(" ");
      for(int i = 0; i<attributes.size(); i++){
         item->node().toElement().setAttribute(attributes.at(i).split("=").at(0),
                                               attributes.at(i).split("=").at(1));
      }
      break;
   case 2: // Left it as it is
      item->node().setNodeValue(value.toString());   // This works - QTreeView is updated
      break;
}
```